# How to mention another user in a list item?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-comments

Is there anyway that I can mention another user in a list item? For example, I have a multi line field called Comments.

In order to mention another user, I will type in that field @username. Then the mentioned user will receive a notification.

I know that this can be achieve in the Discussion Board, but how about in a List?

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing a custom workflow or an event receiver perhaps.

Check if you have strings of the format @UserName, if it exists, send an email alert!

Thats the only way I can think of unless, the users have subscribed to alerts.

Comment: I have thought about that. But the problem with this solution is that when using @username, the username can't be validated. For example, user can mention the wrong name without knowing it and then the email won't work. It would be better if it acts the same like the people picker or in discussion board where list of username show up.

Comment: Oh yes. Then you might have to put validation on the client side as well. 
Put event listeners in JavaScript at every key press :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread.

But, this is now possible with the new [List comments](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/09/all-you-need-to-know-about-commenting-in-lists/) feature in SharePoint online.

You can get a colleague’s attention to an list item by @mentioning them within list comments & they will receive an email notification.

Check detailed information at: [SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists: @mention people in list comments](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/12/mention-people-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists-comments/)